# Trying to update a paragraph element with JS but it creates a new page

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I have a form that collects data and puts it into an array

So i'm trying to create a page that once a button is pushed it runs this function and I want it to display underneath the form in a paragraph that i have assigned an ID to so that more data can be added.

However when I run the page it shows the table in a new page and deletes the form. Any ideas on how to have it display the table underneath the form?

Here is the call...

```
document.getElementById("appTable").innerHTML = showAppointments(appointmentArr);
```

Here is the function...

```
function showAppointments(appointmentArr){ //Function to display all data in a table
        var splitAppointment = new Array();         
        for(var i=0; i <= appointmentArr.length; i++){
            if(i==0){ //Draw intitial table only once
                document.writeln('<table border="1">');
                document.writeln("<tr>");
                document.writeln("<th>Priority</th>");
                document.writeln("<th>Date</th>");
                document.writeln("<th>Start</th>");
                document.writeln("<th>End</th>");
                document.writeln("<th>Subject</th>");
                document.writeln("<th>Venue</th>");
                document.writeln("</tr>");
            }else{
                splitAppointment = appointmentArr[i-1].split(';'); //Split the main array by ";" into a seperate array to be read at current index
                document.writeln("<tr>");
                for(var j=0; j < splitAppointment.length; j++){ //Display each row of data in the table for single appointment details 
                    document.writeln("<td>"+splitAppointment[j]+"</td>");
                }
            document.writeln("</tr>");  
            }
        }
        document.writeln("</table>");
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using document.writeln, you need to create the elements and add them to the DOM, like so:

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.setAttribute("border","1");
document.body.appendChild(table);
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
table.appendChild(tr);
var th = document.createElement("th");
tr.appendChild(th);
```

Comment: Do i put that into the function or the html ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using a different way.

I wrote all the information to a variable and then outputted the variable using innerHTML and it wrote all the data for the table correctly on the same page.

eg.

table += ''
...

and so forth